# How to detect if a file exist in a project folder?

Tags: c#, file-exists

I am having a collection of images in my project folder.

how to detect if a image exist in my project folder? I am using c#. Thanks.

Comment: Could you specify exactly when you need to detect those? Are we talking about before compilation, or when the compiled program is running?

Comment: I have a listview of items, data bind to a list of files on my local folder Z that consist of various files like .doc, .xls, etc.

In my project(solution) files, I have a folder with a collection of image file, namely doc.png, xls.png etc.

What I want to do now is to loop the files in folder Z, detect the file type, and try to return like: 

string type = Path.GetExtension(filepath);
string path = @"image/" + type + ".png";
if(Exist(path))
{
    return path;
}
else
{
    return @"image/other.png";
}

because the files located in my solution folder, so I not sure will it works after deploy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists("pathtofile"))
  //it exist
else
  //it does not exist
```

EDITED MY ANSWER AFTER THE COMMENT OF THE QUESTION:

I copied the code and changed the exits function, this should work

```
string type = Path.GetExtension(filepath); 
string path = @"image/" + type + ".png"; 
//if(System.IO.File.Exists(path)) I forgot to use the full path
if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path)))
 { return path; } 
else 
 { return @"image/other.png"; }
```

This will indeed work when your app is deployed

Comment: An alternative is to use `FileInfo`, if you need to also get timestamps and other basic information.

Comment: @Steven: that is correct if you want the info of the file but File.Exists has a better performance if you only need to know if the exist

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested it as an alternative if you're also going to need additional information, not as a general replacement.

Comment: @VHanded: Please mark the answer as Accepted if this answer helped you. Then the answer gets marked and other people can see that the problem is solved

Comment: Sorry maybe my question is not clear enough, but this is not what I asked for. I just updated my question in my comment in my question, but the editor cramped all together.

Comment: I edited my answer to your update, I hope this is clear enough

Comment: Won't the path be relative to the current directory the application is started from?

Comment: ok sorry my mistake, it must be Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path), I will edit my answer again

Comment: No problem liked to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I tested it, and realize that the GetCurrentDirectory() is actually return the bin directory. The image folder is not located in the bin directory. Any workaround??

Comment: You can use ..\ or ../ to go 1 folder up in the structure. example: string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"../image/" + type + ".png"; 
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path)) ...

Answer (score 2):

The question is a little unclear but I get the impression that you're after 
the path the exe has been installed in?

```
  class Program
  {
    static Dictionary<string, string> typeImages = null;

    static string GetImagePath(string type)
    {
      if (typeImages == null)
      {
        typeImages = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        string path = Path.Combine(appPath, @"image/");
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
          typeImages.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).ToUpper(), Path.GetFullPath(file));
        }
      }

      if (typeImages.ContainsKey(type))
        return typeImages[type];
      else
        return typeImages["OTHER"];
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("File for XLS="+GetImagePath("XLS"));
      Console.WriteLine("File for ZZZ=" + GetImagePath("ZZZ"));
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
```

This will give you an image folder that will be wherever the exe is installed.
In the dev environment, you'll have to create an images dir under debug and release in the app path because that's where VS puts the exe's.

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.Exists(Path Here)` If your using a temp path use `Path.GetTempPath()`

EDIT: Sorry, same answer as above!

Answer (score -3):

you could use

```
string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

to get a list of the files in the folder and then iterate through them until you find what your looking for (or not)

or you could try to open the file in a try catch block and if you get an exception it means the file does not exist.

Comment: Not as efficient as the `File.Exists` or `FileInfo.Exists` methods.

Comment: Is it really less efficient? You'd use it in a lazy evaluation style or get the files on startup and keep the list.