# How to check File Exists c#

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I would like to check file exists in the same folder where is my program. If is do something. How i can fix that ?

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (File.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "tres.xml"))
         Upload("tres.xml");

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if a file exist in a project folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446915/how-to-detect-if-a-file-exist-in-a-project-folder)

Comment: Use `Path.Combine` instead of concatenating the path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is that [`GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) returns no `\` at the end. That's even  documented:

> The string returned by this method consists of all characters in the
>   path up to **but not including the last** `DirectorySeparatorChar` or
>   `AltDirectorySeparatorChar`

Use [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the correct directory separator char:

```
string path =  Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "tres.xml");
if(File.Exists(path))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just simply use:

```
File.Exists("tres.xml");
```

This checks the current directory of your .exe

Comment: Note that it is the _current directory of your .exe_, that means `bin\Debug` (if you run from VS) and not your project root.